# Xcode 9 Bug : Existing Project is returning response code of 500 for all api request

Tags: ios, xcode

I was working on a project which was working fine (all API request returns appropriate data) on Xcode 8.3.3. But After updating Xcode to version 9 all API request is returning a response code of 500. Does Xcode 9 send some additional parameter in API request which causes the service to fail?

Comment: This question only makes sense if you assume by "API" you actually mean just "RESTful API".  Even then, it's pretty obvious that your question lacks detail. Are you claiming that every single REST call you make results in the server responding with a 500 code? Or just the RESTful service you happen to be calling. More context is needed for this to be a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Answer :  https://9to5mac.com/2017/06/21/apple-ios-11-beta-2/

It has this statement in the body:
“ Added support for HTTP brotli content encoding to URLSession. By default, HTTP requests contain a br value (in addition to gzip and deflate) for the Accept-Encoding HTTP header, informing the web server that the user agent supports brotli encoding. The web server can send an HTTP body with Content-Encoding: br in the HTTP header to indicate that the content is brotli-encoded. URLSession automatically decompresses the HTTP body data and passes the decoded data back to the client in the same way it does for Content-Encoding: gzip. For binary compatibility reasons, URLSession brotli support is enabled only for apps built using the iOS 11 SDK. (27724985)"

With Xcode 9  iOs 11:- For all the  network request, if the ‘Accept-Encoding’ header value is not assigned for a request then it will automatically sets brotli encoding for ‘Accept-Encoding’ header for the request.The solution is to set ‘Accept-Encoding’ = ‘gzip, deflate’.

Comment: add this add as header let headers = ["Content-Type": "application/json"]

Comment: Or you could fix your server not to throw an exception when the client says it accepts brotli encoded data.

Comment: Based on this answer, your issue has absolutely nothing to do with Xcode. The change is in iOS 11.